# Middle Square Algorithm in R

Tags: r, random

I have been struggling with this for a while. I am trying to make a Middle Square Algorithm but I can't make it work for some reason. I am fairly new to R, so I'm not that confident in it yet.

```
seed=123456890
nxt=seed
find=as.character(nxt)
find=as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(find,"")))
max=length(find)
middle=ceiling(max/2)
partstart=middle-2
partend=middle+3
part=(partstart:partend)
part=as.numeric(paste(part,collapse=""))
gens=c(part)

for(i in 1:10){
    nxt=part^2
    find=as.character(nxt)
    find=as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(find,"")))
    max=length(find)
    middle=ceiling(max/2)
    partstart=middle-2
    partend=middle+3
    part=(partstart:partend)
    part=as.numeric(paste(part,collapse=""))
    gens=c(gens,part)
}
cat(gens)
```

When I run the code, this is the output:

```
345678 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789 456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error. You are creating a numeric sequence.

```
part=(partstart:partend)
```

Change it for

```
part=find[partstart:partend]
```

For your example, result should yield

```
345689 500884 884781 837417 267231 124073 941093 656034 380609 863210 131504
```